# Calling window.open opens a window, but then it suddently gets minimized

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html, window

I make a call to`window.open` which opens up the desired URL, but then the window suddenly gets minimized without my interaction.

Why is this?

**Update:**
The window was being opened on a `onclick` event (asp.net) and I then injected the HTML.  A linkbutton control was used, now when I converted it to a `asp:button`, it is not minimizing. Could you explain this?

Comment: What browser? If its Firefox I can kinda understand. FF sometimes get confused and if you close it while maximized, next time it runs new windows might start maximized. I guess it could work minimized too but I've never seen that. Clear out your browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try adding size attributes, examples [here](http://www.w3schools.com/HTMLDOM/met_win_open.asp).